# Long Process in ASP.NET Web Forms - Browser Timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, webforms, async-await

I realise this question has been asked in different variations but with newer features to .net (e.g. async await) I wonder what solution is the best.

I have a C# .Net Web Forms app that has a long running task: The task handles a user request where they upload a csv data file, serialises into object, and imports to a database. The task can take a few minutes and the browser regularly times out - this causes usability issues.

I have seen many solutions whereas the user will upload the data and then the task is carried out in the background. The page will then call the server intermittently to request the status of the task, thus keeping the user informed of the progress.

I would like to know how this is achieved? The options I see on the table:

- Windows Service
- Web Service - how is this hosted: IIS or a windows service?
- Async, Await - is this a possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could take two different approaches.

The first would be a pull approach, you would be keeping the state of the process per user in the server, perhaps in session, and having the process update that state, then the client can pull the actual state via ajax regularly. The ajax call is made from the client's browser, and the function can be put in the same web page that the client is viewing, there's no need to separate it if it's going to be used only from there.

The second could be a push approach, which is a bit more complex but gives you other possibilities. You would need to use a library like signalr https://www.asp.net/signalr, that allows you to communicate from the server to the client's browser, call JS functions, and push the updated state to the client's form. That could create a more functional two-way communication and a better user experience in exchange of a bit more complexity.

Comment: thanks for the comment. Where would you suggest I actually run the process though? As I said, if I do it directly in the APP, the thread is tied up and so the browser hangs until complete.

Comment: you could start a new thread and call the process in that thread, the main thread would return to the client while the new thread would be busy processing and updating its state

Comment: I have managed to come to a solution by running these processes in a parallel thread and then making ajax calls to the process at small intervals to request a progress update. However, I'm not confident I am using the correct technique. I would previously have thought I should be using some sort of service here.

Comment: I'm not sure if I got that right but if by "service" you mean having your process running in the background as a windows service, it could be done that way, but that wouldn't affect performance much. I would take that approach if the goal is having accessibility from different callers, like for instance if you want to call this process from different web sites or executables, that way the trouble of making it a service would worth the while